# Apache Bench Load Testing for REST Web Service

Tags: apache, rest, apachebench

I am load testing my REST web service using apache bench.

this is working for me now

```
ab -n 300 -c 10 http://server:9535/rest/1_0/query/X?accountId=A&startDate=2014-01-01&endDate=2016-01-01
```

but I want to parameterize the values of accountId, startdate, enddate. Is it possible that rather than hardcoding these values in a URL, I specify a file containing lots of permutations of input values?